# How to find the part of the regexp pattern that matched the input in java?

Tags: java, regex

I have pattern "abc|de.|ghi" and an input of "def". How do I find the part of the pattern that matched "def"? So, in this example the result I want is "de.". Not "def", which is all I have been able to get using group and start/end methods.

In code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("abc|de.|ghi");
Matcher m = p.matcher("def");
if(matcher.find()) {
    // Here I want to get the String "de." somehow
}
```

Comment: should `.` in your input match a single character

Comment: what if the input is `.ef` or `d.f`

Comment: This is just an example of the pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's kind of round about, but you can do what you want with capture groups:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(abc)|(de.)|(ghi)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("def");
if(m.find()) {
    if (m.group(1) != null)
        System.out.println("Matched \"abc\"");
    if (m.group(2) != null)
        System.out.println("Matched \"de.\"");
    if (m.group(3) != null)
        System.out.println("Matched \"ghi\"");
}
```

Comment: Given @andrewdotn's answer, this is the best solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

So,you want to return the regex which matched the input..i guess theres no such method in Pattern or Matcher class to return that exact pattern separated by or

So,you could do it this way

```
public static String getMatchedRegexPattern(String inputRegex,String input) throws Exception
{
    if(Pattern.compile("(?<!\\\\)([\\(\\)\\[\\]])").matcher(inputRegex).find())throw new Exception("Groups,brackets not supported");
    for(String regex:inputRegex.split("(?<!\\\\)\\|"))//split only if | is not escaped
    {
    if(Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input).matches())
        return regex;
    }
    return "";
}
```

You could call it as

```
getMatchedRegexPattern("abc|de.|ghi","def");
```

Comment: This is a very specific solution given this exact regex and given it is a very simple regex. I could be wrong, but I think the OP wants a general solution to find which part of the regex string marched when there are ORed terms

Comment: @Bohemian indeed you are right..op should make it more clear..hope he responds soon to our comments..:)

Comment: Yes, too specific. I know the regex, but I don't know the input.

Answer (score 1):

There’s no easy way of doing this with `Pattern` in the standard library.

The [source code for `Pattern`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/d3912e74ec28/src/share/classes/java/util/regex/Pattern.java) uses a recursive-descent parser to create a tree of `Node` objects which each support a `match()` method. For example, to evaluate `|`, there is a `Branch` subclass at line 4107 that stores a list of possible alternatives. Its `match()` method tries each alternative, and returns `true` if any one of the alternatives matches and the successor node matches. Otherwise it returns `false`.

Groups are saved by inserting special `GroupHead` and `GroupTail` nodes into the parse tree, which save the start and end position of each group into private variables of the `Pattern` class.

To find out which parts of the pattern caused the match, the node objects would need to know the parts of the pattern that caused them to be created. The parser simply doesn’t store that information in the nodes it creates. The original pattern is stored in a `temp` array, and the recursive-descent parser keeps a `cursor` index into the `temp` array as it parses. The parser helper methods like `peek()` and `accept()`, which are defined starting at line 1567, simply increment `cursor` as needed. When nodes are created, the value of `cursor` simply isn’t stored anywhere. But that value is necessary to reconstruct which parts of the pattern corresponds to the match.

It’s understandable why `Pattern` doesn’t save this information: it would slow down all regular expression evaluations, but the additional functionality would hardly ever be used.

One possibility is to create a modified version of `Pattern` that does the appropriate bookkeeping to trace matches back to the parts of the patterns that they came from. For storing which part of the pattern each node corresponds to, you may be able to get away with making the `Node()` constructor stash a copy of the `cursor` field. But for using that data to find which parts of the pattern matched, you’ll need to update every `Node` subclass’s `match()` method to store the range based on the semantics of each subclass of `Node`….

Good luck!